# Multiple file upload limit

Tags: php, kohana

I have a function in my website (built with kohana) for image uploading, so user can more than one photo per one time. But when I am choosing more than 20 images, as a result I get only first 20 images uploaded, other images just skipped and not uploaded. May Kohana have save limit for file uploading? Or it's a problem with hosting? 
As a Image class used standart kohana's image class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your php ini file, [max_file_uploads](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.max-file-uploads) shows maximum number of files allowed to be uploaded simultaneously. By default 20 files are allowed. Use below code to set maximum file upload limit.

```
ini_set('max_file_uploads',1000);
```

Comment: sure but better way, add this in config files.

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably a problem with your hosting, create a blank PHP file and add the following

```
<?php

// Show all information, defaults to INFO_ALL
phpinfo();

?>
```

Browse to the page and take a look, it will show you the maximum upload limits of the web server, if you have reached these you may have to contact your host.